# Labeling runways for localization and detection using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image: Sample Ariel view of Runway that needs to be localized**strong text**]

Shown above is a sample image of runway that needs to be localized(a bounding box around runway)
i know how image classification is done in tensorflow, My question is how do I **label** this image for training?
 I want model to output 4 numbers to draw bounding box.
In CS231n they say that we use a classifier and a localization head.
but how does my model knows where are the runnway in 400x400 images?

In short How do I  **LABEL** this image for training? So that after training my model detects and localizes(draw bounding box around this runway) runways from input images.
Please feel free to give me links to lectures, videos, github tutorials from where I can learn about this.
**********Not CS231n********** I already took that lecture and couldnt understand how to solve using their approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predict bounding boxes, then the labels are also bounding boxes. This is what most object detection systems use for training. You can just have bounding box labels, or if you want to detect multiple object classes, then also class labels for each bounding box would be required.

Comment: How do I train?

Comment: @MuhammadUmerJavaid Train what? That's an extremely vague question.

Comment: Matias, you have been long enough on SO to know that you are suppose to close and downvote questions which are too vague and looks like 'I need something, have no idea how to do it'

Answer (score 1):

Collect data from google or any resources that contains only runway photos (From some closer view). I would suggest you to use a pre-trained image classification network (like VGG, Alexnet etc.) and fine tune this network with downloaded runway data.

After building a good image classifier on runway data set you can use any popular algorithm to generate region of proposal from the image.

Now take all regions of proposal and pass them to classification network one by one and check weather this network is classifying given region of proposal as positive or negative. If it classifying as positively then most probably your object(Runway) is present in that region. Otherwise it's not.

If there are a lot of region of proposal in which object is present according to classifier then you can use non maximal suppression algorithms to reduce number of positive proposals.